# How to register by UIImage instead of button in IOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

As I'm new in the field of IOS I'm a bit confused about how to use UIImage instead of button. I did a simple register page with a button instead of image. I want to give same action and alert in the UIImage also, here is my button action code:

```
(IBAction)regst:(id)sender
{

    REG *rr=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"REG" inManagedObjectContext:a.managedObjectContext];

    rr.name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.txt1.text];
    rr.username=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.txt2.text];
    rr.password=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.txt3.text];
    rr.age=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.txt4.text];
    rr.email=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.txt5.text];
    [a saveContext ];

    if 
(self.txt1.text.length && self.txt2.text.length && self.txt3.text.length && self.txt4.text.length && self.txt5.text.length!=0)

    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ALERT VIEW" message:@"REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];

        self.txt1.text=@"";
        self.txt2.text=@"";
        self.txt3.text=@"";
        self.txt4.text=@"";
        self.txt5.text=@"";
```

Comment: can you edit your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the text from the button and use [setBackgroundImage:forState:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage:forState:) if the button is set in code, or simply just change the background image of the button in the storyboard if its made in the storyboard